# Button on the previously hidden div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My program has 2 divs with buttons, one is hidden and another is shown. When I click on shown div's button, it switches these 2 divs, hides first and shows second. But button on the second doesn't interact with elements on the sibling divs as buttons from the first div, even though the code is exactly the same. 
(html)

```
<div class="first_two_guesses">
  <input type="text" class="guess" id='first_guess' placeholder="first guess">
  <input type="text" class="guess" id='second_guess' placeholder="second guess">      
  <button type='button' class="btn-add">Submit</button>
</div>
<div class='word_guesses' style='display: none;'>
  <input type='text' class='guess' id='word_or_letter' placeholder='letter or word'>
  <button type='button' class='btn-guess'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

(jquery)

```
$('.btn-add').on('click', function(){   
   ... do someting ...
  $('.first_two_guesses').hide();
  $('.word_guesses').show();
}

$('.btn-guess').on('click', function(){   
  ... do the same thing ...
}
```

Comment: question shortage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. By attaching a delegated event to an element that is viewable in the HTML when the jQuery is run.

So if a.someClass is hidden when jQuery is run, you should attach a delegated event to the body, so it will run when there is a viewable a.someClass element in the future, for example:

```
$('body').on('click','input.a.someClass',function(){
  alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put ending parenthesis(`)`) in your code. See below:

```js
$('.btn-add').on('click', function(){   
  $('.first_two_guesses').hide();
  $('.word_guesses').show();
});

$('.btn-guess').on('click', function(){   
  $('.first_two_guesses').show();
  $('.word_guesses').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first_two_guesses">
  <input type="text" class="guess" id='first_guess' placeholder="first guess">
  <input type="text" class="guess" id='second_guess' placeholder="second guess">      
  <button type='button' class="btn-add">Submit</button>
</div>
<div class='word_guesses' style='display: none;'>
  <input type='text' class='guess' id='word_or_letter' placeholder='letter or word'>
  <button type='button' class='btn-guess'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: please comment down the reason why this answer is down voted.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to switch visibility of html elements.

```
$('.btn-add').on('click', function(){   
  $('.first_two_guesses').toggle();
  $('.word_guesses').toggle();
});

$('.btn-guess').on('click', function(){   
  $('.first_two_guesses').toggle();
  $('.word_guesses').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kjbphn7m/1/).

```
$('.btn-add').on('click', function(){   
   //... do someting ...
  $('.first_two_guesses').hide();
  $('.word_guesses').show();
});

$('.btn-guess').on('click', function(){   
 // ... do the same thing ...
   $('.first_two_guesses').show();
  $('.word_guesses').hide();
});
```

I have edited your question, what i understood your problem is as if you want to toggle between two button clicks. Try to use ID selector with your elements.
An ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one